# Issue with AD AZURE ASP.NET, redirected to the domain root

Tags: asp.net, azure, razor

I am using Microsoft application to handle AZURE AD connection
my redirect id has this form:

https://exxample.com/appname/

After user is authenticated with AD azure, the url is redirected to
https://example.com/
without the appname

This issue is faced with all customers, I am obliged to put a jsvascript redirect in index.html in the root to redirect the user to
https://example.com/appname

Is the a way to make the redirectURI inclusing a full url in the form I provided to work correctly instead of redirecting to the root

Comment: Are you facing any errors in the authentication process? Can you share it?

Comment: I am not getting any error message, I also added a waiting time, before checking if the user is authenticated, but the user is always showing authenticated=false

Comment: @DasariKamali I updated my question: I added this code: @{
        string result = null;

        try
        {
            result = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("name").Value;
        }.... to check the user name but's always showing not connected.

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding a "/" to the redirectURI
but now the application is redirected to the domain without the app: my redirect is https://domainname.com/appname, after azure ad authentication, I am redirected to https://domainname.com with the appname

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a solution to this issue by implementing a default.html page in the root domain,and I asked users to connect t
https://www.thisdomain.org?id=myapp instead of https://www.thisdomain.org/myapp/
when user connects to this page,

- Javascript checks if the cookie customer has value:
- case 1: if yes: it redirects to https://www.thisdomain.org/myapp/
- case 2 :if no : it fills the cookie customer=myapp, then redirect to https://www.thisdomain.org/myapp/

case 1 : this means that user has already connected to the domain root, and is  already authenticated with azure.

case 2 : this means that user has not yet connected to the domain root, and is  not already authenticated with azure:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
    <title>My AppConnection using AD AZURE</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>May APP Connection using AD AZURE</title>
    <script>
        function getCookie(cookieName) {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].split('=');
                if (cookie[0] === cookieName) {
                    return cookie[1];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        function redirect(url, time) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = url;
            }, time);
        }                        
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="logo.png" />
    <script>
        const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const containsId = queryParams.has('id');
        var name;
        if (containsId) {
            name = queryParams.get('id');
            //console.log(name);
            document.cookie = 'customer=' + name;
            if (name !== 'null') {
                console.log('1:', name);              
                redirect('/' + name, 2000);
            }
        } else {
            name = getCookie('customer');
            if (name == 'null') {
                console.log('3: Cookie not found or is null');
                redirect('/?id=default', 2000);
            } else {
                console.log('2:', name);             
                redirect('/' + name, 2000);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```